# interactionCreate not working DiscordJS v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im new to coding slash commands and for some reason my interactionCreate just stops or doesnt work? this doesn't apply the same for messageCreate so. my slash command handler works but ill put it here just in case

my slash command handler:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')

const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN
const guild = process.env.GUILD
const appid = process.env.APPID

module.exports = async (client, Discord) => {
    const slashCommands = [];

    fs.readdirSync('./slashCommands/').forEach(dir => {
        const slashCommandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./slashCommands/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of slashCommandFiles) {
            const slashCommand = require(`../slashCommands/${dir}/${file}`)
            slashCommands.push(slashCommand.data.toJSON());
        }
    });
    const rest = new REST({ version: '9'}).setToken(token);
    (async () => {
        try {
            console.log("Started registering slash command files!")

            await rest.put(
                guild
                ? Routes.applicationGuildCommands(appid, guild)
                : Routes.applicationGuildCommands(appid),
                {
                    body: slashCommands
                }
            );
            console.log('Successfully registered slash commands')
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })();

}
```

my interactionCreate file:

```js
module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        const slashCommand = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName)
        if(!slashCommand) return;
        try {
            await slashCommand.execute(client, interaction)
        } catch (err) {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            await interaction.reply({ content: "There was an error trying to execute this command!", ephemeral: true})
        }
    })
    }
```

the file i want to execute:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('hello')
    .setDescription('cool'),
    async execute(client, interaction){
        await interaction.reply({ content: "Hello!"})
    }
}
```

it also says "The application did not respond" when i try to execute the slash command. All the file directories given in the slash command handler are all correct aswell

Comment: What do you do with your `interactionCreate` file?

Comment: What intents are you using?